# Unknown column in 'field list' MySQL Query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate

My Stack Trace

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'
```

5 minutes later my Stack Trace was

```
Named parameter lastName not bound
```

What is the problem in this query?

**My interface**

```
public interface InstructorDao extends JpaRepository <Instructor, Long> {
    
    @Query (nativeQuery=true, value ="select i from Instructor as i where i.firstName like %:firstName% or i.lastName like %:firstName%")
    List <Instructor> findInstructorByfirstName (@Param ("firstName") String firstName);
```

**My entity**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Instructor")
public class Instructor {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "instructor_id", nullable = false)
    private Long instructorId;
    
    @Basic
    @Column (name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Basic  
    @Column (name = "lastName", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String lastName;
    
    @Basic
    @Column (name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String instructorSummary;
    
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "instructor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set <Course> courses = new HashSet<>(); 'i' in 'field lis
```

Also, if anybody knows where I can find all material about different SQL languages, I will be very grateful, because sometimes professionals write

```
select i from Instructor as i where i.firstName like %:firstName% or i.lastName like %:firstName%   or 
select i from Instructor as i where i.user.userEmail =:userEmail  or
select * from courses as c where c.course_id in (select e.course_id from enrolled_in as e where e.student_id = :studentId)
```

I must know all these combinations!

Comment: remove `as` from `select i from Instructor as i  ...`

Comment: remove as, and try remove as i, don work  
 Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you specified the query as the native query so you will have to use `*` to select all.

```
select * from table i
```

OR

```
Select i.* from table i
```

Comment: oh tnx, i remove nativeQuery and everything work!  Do you know where i could read and learn something more about this SQL Query?

Comment: There are many tutorials or articles on these. You can go through some of them, please mark the answer as accepted solution if it helped you.